# How do I recreate Enumerable's count method?

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I'm trying to recreate Enumerable's `count` method as found in "[Projects: Advanced Building Blocks](http://www.theodinproject.com/courses/ruby-programming/lessons/advanced-building-blocks)".

The definition in the Ruby docs is that `count`

> "Returns the number of items in enum through enumeration. **If an argument is given, the number of items in enum that are equal to item are counted**. If a block is given, it counts the number of elements yielding a true value."

What exactly is the default argument though?

The way I approached this so far is as follows:
The parameter is set to something when no argument is passed so:

Case, when self is not a string:

1. when argument given and block given (eg. `[1,2,3].count(3) { |x| x == 3 }`):
   returns warning and count of the argument.
2. when argument given and no block (eg. `[1,2,3].count(3)`):
   returns count of the argument.
3. when no argument and no block (eg. `[1,2,3].count`): 
   returns size of the instance.
4. else (no argument given and block given) (eg. `[1,2,3].count { |x| x == 3 }`: 
   returns count based on specifications given in block.

The two questions I have are basically:

- What is the default argument for count?
- What is the global variable used in warning?

Here's my code:

```
module Enumerable

  def my_count arg='default value'
    if kind_of? String
      # code
    else # I think count works the same way for hashes and arrays
      if arg != 'default value' 
        count = 0
        for index in 0...size
          count += 1 if arg == self[index]
        end
        warn "#{'what goes here'}: warning: block not used" if block_given?
        count
      else
        return size if arg == 'default value' && !block_given?
        count = 0
        for index in 0...size
          count += 1 if yield self[index]
        end
        count
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Since Ruby 1.9, Enumerable is not mixed-in by the String class, so you can assume the receiver is not a string. There is no default argument.  There are a variable number of arguments: zero or one.  You want `def my_count(*args)`, then check `args.size`, which could be zero, one or more than one.  (If more than one, you might want to raise an `ArgumentError` exception).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a default argument. Use `*args` to collect all the arguments into an array.

```
def my_count(*args, &block)

  if args.length == 1 && !block_given?
    # use args[0]
  elsif args.length == 1 && block_given?
    # use block
  elsif args.length == 0 && !block_given?
    # no argument/block
  else
    # raise error
  end
end
```